# Fetching SVN logs locally

Tags: svn, ssh

I have root access to a server hosting a `SVN` respository (via `SSH`).

I need to do some heavy log crunching, basically I have to fetch the revision of each `diff` using:

`svn diff -c ARG`

where `ARG` is the revision number. I have to fetch this information for all the revisions, which takes time if I query the server remotely.

So my question is, if I can `SSH` into the server, is there *anyway* I can fetch the logs locally rather than fetching them remotely?

Comment: +1 for well formatted first question

Comment: Why do you need to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get access to the server, you can use svn in file system mode, to query locally, using file:// url. You can check [relevant manual page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch08.html#svn-ch-8-sect-1.2.3) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can `checkout` the repository right on the server and perform any operations you need.

When you'll check it out - specify local path with `path:///` prefix

Comment: But I can already navigate to the SVN folder and I see: `logs`, `db`, `hooks` and all such folders. Can't anything be done there? Assuming I do checkout the repository on the server, does `svn diff` take local path?

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly, thanks. But I am going to accept Bruce's answer since has less reputation :-)

Comment: @S Singh: ok, let +1 him then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use always a url e.g:

```
svn diff <url> -rREV:REV
```

if you need to use ssh you may add the `svn+ssh` protocol.

```
svn diff svn+ssh://my-username@my-server/my-home/my-repo -rREV:REV
```

Edit: You **do not** need to checkout the repository

Another thing would be according to your comment. If you want to have an operation which only uses local logs you may use a distributed version control system like git. Git e.g. supports direct access to remote svn repositories. Then everything will be mirrored.

Comment: But how does this make it a local operation?

Comment: It is a central source code repository so it will always be some sort of remote transmission involved.